# printf long changes variable when it's digits is more than 9 chars

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I have this simple code in C, whenever I enter an id number that longer than 9 digits, it prints a different number. What's the wrong?

```
void main() {
    long id1;
    double l1, w1;
    printf("enter studint 1 id,lenght and weight: \n");
    scanf("%ld %lf %lf", &id1, &l1, &w1);

    printf("STUDINTS INFORMATION:");
    printf("\n\n%-10.0ld\t %-4.3lf\t %-4.3lf\n", id1, l1, w1); 
}
```

Comment: start by checking the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: "I enter an id number that longer than 9 digits" --> What was the number entered? What was printed?

Comment: A `long` range may only be [-2,147,483,647 ... 2,147,483,647].  A number outside that range is asking for trouble.  Use a wider integer type.

Comment: `%-10.0ld` for `id1` seems incorrect: if `id1 == 0` the output will be just 10 spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use type `long` for `id1` which may have range of just `-2147483647` to `2147483647` depending on the target system architecture. This type cannot be used to store larger numbers on your system.

Incidentally, the format `%-10.0ld` for `id1` seems incorrect as the output for the value `0` will be just 10 spaces. The *precision* field does not specify the number of decimals for integers, but the minimum number of digits.

Note also that `main` without arguments should have a prototype of `int main(void)`, and you should test the return value of `scanf()` to avoid undefined behavior on invalid input.

To solve your problem, here are possible solutions:

- You could use type `double` but I would not advise so.
- You could try type `long long int`, but this type may not be fully supported on your system.
- I suggest you use a character string for your purpose.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char id1[20];
    double l1, w1;

    printf("enter student 1 id, height and weight:\n");
    if (scanf("%19s%lf%lf", id1, &l1, &w1) != 3) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("STUDENT INFORMATION:\n");
    printf("\n%-10s\t %-4.3f\t %-4.3f\n", id1, l1, w1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, IDs are better stored as strings.  Not only is it more flexible if the ID someday contains letters, but it avoids problems like this.  IDs are not arithmetic, i.e. you cannot typically get anything out of adding or subtracting them, so you may as well just store them as strings.  Then you can easily support any length, regardless of the width of various integer types on your system.

Answer (score 0):

That's because range of long in C is from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.
So, when you try to save a number longer than 9 digits it gets out of range.

For more details on the range of variables in C: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm

Comment: This tutorial is incorrect. The range of type `long` is *at least* `-2147483647` to `2147483647` but it may be much larger, as is the case on 64-bit linux systems. Your correctly diagnosed the OP's problem, but the link is misleading.